# How to run code after the screen is initialized for the first time?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

The application uses Caliburn.Micro and its screens to display tabs to a user.

I am aware of IScreen.OnInitialize() method which is called before the screen is made visible. I would like to have a code triggered the screen is fully visible to the user - the tab representing the screen should be there but does not need to be necessarily selected.

I would like to trigger data load just after the screen is fully initialized and visible (and most of the code is run on the UI thread natively without marshaling).

This is how it looks like now.

```
public class MyViewModel : 
    Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive,
    IHandleWithTask<DatabaseItemChangedMessage>
{
    // This method is called by EventAggregator
    public async Task Handle(DatabaseItemChangedMessage message)
    {
        await this.LoadData(true);
    }

    protected override void OnInitialize()
    {
        base.OnInitialize();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.LoadData(false).Wait()).ContinueWith(
            task =>
                {
                    if (task.Exception != null)
                    {
                        Execute.OnUIThread(
                            () =>
                            {
                                App.HandleException(task.Exception);
                                this.TryClose();
                            });
                    }
                });
    }

    protected async Task LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            this.WorkStarted("Loading data...");

            TLoadedData loadedData;
            ISession transaction = null;
            // using (var transaction = this.DataItemRepository.BeginTransaction())
            // {
                 loadedData = await this.LoadDataInternal(transaction);
            //     transaction.Commit();
            // }

            Execute.OnUIThread(() => this.SetLoadedData(loadedData));
        }
        finally
        {
            this.WorkFinished();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SetLoadedData(TLoadedData loadedData)
    {
        // Updates CollectionView's source using loadedData
    }

    protected virtual async Task<TLoadedData> LoadDataInternal(ISession session)
    {
        // loads data from database and returns them
    }

    protected virtual void WorkStarted(string description)
    {
        // Sets properties using to display progress
    }

    protected virtual void WorkFinished()
    {
        // Unsets properties using to display progress
    }
}

// Just an empty class for EventAggregator purposes
public class DatabaseItemChangedMessage
{
}

// Stores data loaded from the database
public class TLoadedData
{
}
```

Comment: You're synchronously waiting on asynchronous methods.  Don't do that.  `await` them.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `Execute.OnUIThread` at all in a program like this if you use the TPL correctly; due to the fact that continuations will marshal to the original context.

Comment: 1) If I remove the `Execute.OnUIThread` in the `OnInitialize` method, "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this." is thrown when instantiating a window inside the `App.HandleException` method.

Comment: 2) I need to use the `Execute.OnUIThread` as I have found no way how to start the `LoadData` code on the UI thread just after the screen is made visible. Do you have a hint what to subscribe to or what to override?

Comment: If I put loadData just inside the `OnInitialize` method without starting it as a new task, it will block creating of the screen before all the data is loaded (so the user will do not see response for his action).

Comment: `LoadData` is an asynchronous method.  It should be called from the UI thread *because it won't block*.  You need to not synchronously wait for it to finish so as to not block the UI thread.  In order for it to actually be asynchronous (as it's API indicates that it is) it shouldn't be calling any long running synchronous methods.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the main issue with your code is that you are creating a whole new `Task` for the purpose of executing an existing asynchronous operation. When in fact what you should be doing is just initiating that operation, awaiting it, and handling any exception as necessary.

For example:

```
public class MyViewModel : 
    Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive,
    IHandleWithTask<DatabaseItemChangedMessage>
{
    // Ideally, async methods return a Task, but here you have to
    // match the base method signature, so you're stuck with void
    protected override async void OnInitialize()
    {
        base.OnInitialize();

        try
        {
            await this.LoadData(false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            App.HandleException(e);
            this.TryClose();
        }    
    }

    // I added the "flag" parameter, so that it matched the calls from
    // your other code
    protected async Task LoadData(bool flag)
    {
        try
        {
            this.WorkStarted("Loading data...");

            TLoadedData loadedData;
            ISession transaction = null;
            // using (var transaction = this.DataItemRepository.BeginTransaction())
            // {
                 loadedData = await this.LoadDataInternal(transaction);
            //     transaction.Commit();
            // }

            // NOTE: by changing the caller of this method so that it's
            // initiated on the UI thread, now the continuations also run
            // on the UI thread, and you don't need to explicitly invoke them there.
            this.SetLoadedData(loadedData);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.WorkFinished();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not await in OnInitialize as it blocks showing the screen. I prefer show the screen first than load data. I have found no entry point for this so I am starting a background job on a background thread.

Comment: The `await` statement doesn't block, so I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: The OnInitialize method does not finish before the LoadData is done with its work.

Comment: What is there to finish? You call `base.OnInitialize()` (which _will_ finish before you even start `LoadData()`), and then there's nothing else in the method _to_ "finish", other than the `LoadData()` work.

Comment: The framework does not seem to show the screen before the OnInitialize is finished. And the user does not have any visual feedback on his action if the screen is not shown in a timely manner.

Comment: As far as the caller of `OnInitialize()` is concerned, the method _is_ finished as soon as it hits the `await` statement. The only way what you say is happening _could_ be happening is if there is something about the code you haven't shared with us. Of course, since the code example is incomplete, that's entirely possible. That's why it's so important that you post a minimal, _complete_ code example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what using the IViewAware method -->```protected virtual void OnViewReady(object view) { 
} ``` which you get with Screen which gets it from ViewAware via IViewAware.  One of the old hacks along time ago was to place some of the heavy lifting code in there for windows phone and Silverlight long running processes, yet still get working UI.

Comment: @mvermef sounds like there's another answer that'd be useful. I'd upvote the alternate strategy, especially if it's more independent of Caliburn.Micro's framework.